# rails drop down not passing selection to records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, sqlite

still going on my first rails program (ruby 2.0, rails 4.0). I've got a drop down that displays static options from a second model, but when I click on a selection from that drop down, nothing happens. Saving it to the record (presence_of validation turned off) just leaves the field empty.

I'm thinking something in controller or view? Any help?

Sorry for the massive code dump, but I'm so noob that I wasn't sure what was relevant

Contact.rb

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base

attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :email, :zip_code, :favorite_color, :color_id, :name, :hex
belongs_to :color
accepts_nested_attributes_for :color
```

Color.rb

```
class Color < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contacts
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :contacts
  attr_accessible :name, :hex
end
```

contacts_controller.rb

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_contact, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
before_filter :prepare_colors

# GET /contacts
# GET /contacts.json
def index
  @contacts = Contact.all
end

# GET /contacts/1
# GET /contacts/1.json
def show
end

# GET /contacts/new
def new
  @contact = Contact.new
end

# GET /contacts/1/edit
def edit
end

# POST /contacts
# POST /contacts.json
def create
  @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @contact.save
      format.html { redirect_to @contact, notice: 'Contact was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @contact }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
      format.json { render json: @contact.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

# PATCH/PUT /contacts/1
# PATCH/PUT /contacts/1.json
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @contact.update(contact_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @contact, notice: 'Contact was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'edit' }
      format.json { render json: @contact.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

# DELETE /contacts/1
# DELETE /contacts/1.json
def destroy
  @contact.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to contacts_url }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end

private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_contact
    @contact = Contact.find(params[:id])
  end

  def prepare_colors
    @colors = Color.all
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def contact_params
    params.require(:contact).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :zip_code, :favorite_color, :color_id)
  end
```

end

views/contacts/_form.html.erb

```
%= form_for(@contact) do |f| %>
  <% if @contact.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@contact.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this contact from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @contact.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :first_name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :last_name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :zip_code %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :zip_code %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :favorite_color %><br>
    <%= f.collection_select(:color_id, @colors, :id, :name, :include_blank => "Please select") %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

and /views/contacts/index.html

```
h3>Listing contacts</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First name</th>
      <th>Last name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Zip code</th>
      <th>Favorite color</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @contacts.each do |contact| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= contact.first_name %></td>
        <td><%= contact.last_name %></td>
        <td><%= contact.email %></td>
        <td><%= contact.zip_code %></td>
        <td><%= contact.favorite_color %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', contact %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_contact_path(contact) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', contact, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Contact', new_contact_path %>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Strong Params**

First of all, if you're using rails 4.0 you don't need this line:

```
attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :email, :zip_code, :favorite_color, :color_id, :name, :hex
```

This has been replaced with [`strong_params`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html) now, so you should put this into the bottom of your contacts controller:

```
private
def contact_params
    params.require(:contact).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :zip_code, :favorite_color, :color_id, :name, :hex, colors_attributes: [])
end
```

**Fields_For**

The next thing is that you need to include the [`fields_for`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for) tag in your form, like this:

```
<%= f.fields_for :colors do |color| %><br>
    <%= f.collection_select(:color_id, @colors, :id, :name, :include_blank => "Please select") %>
<% end %>
```

I think that will work. Your code was pretty long, so I guess if you have problems implementing it, just leave a comment :)

---

**Update**

You need to add this to your new function:

```
# GET /contacts/new
def new
  @contact = Contact.new
  @contact.color.build

  @colors = Color.all
end
```

Also, I don't know if this will work again, but you might want to edit your collection_select to have this code:

```
<%= f.fields_for :colors do |color| %><br>
    <%= color.collection_select(:color, @colors, :id, :name, :include_blank => "Please select") %>
<% end %>
```

Finally, you should include the :id attribute in your nested_attributes:

```
private
def contact_params
    params.require(:contact).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :zip_code, :favorite_color, :color_id, :name, :hex, colors_attributes: [])
end
```

Comment: Not gonna work, there is no color_id field on Color model, also you don't want to assign new id for a color, but a new color to association.

Comment: Yep, my apologies, you can just add the :color_id into the colors_attributes params hash. Let me revise.....

Comment: getting the error undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass in _form. FYI.

Comment: Added some updates, but it might be worth posting your code on GitHub so I can take a better look (your problem might not just be a problem with your form -- it might be to do with your controller / model setup too) :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I am not entirely sure what is relationship here, but it seems to me that you have two columns in your Contact model which are created for the same reason: favorite_color and colour_id. You are not setting favorite_color value, but you are trying to display it. I guess color_id is to be a foreign_key to contact's favurite color. if so, you need to rename assocaition:

```
belongs_to :favorite_color, class_name: 'Color'
```

Rename color_id column to favorite_color_id, and then inside your view:

```
# form
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :favorite_color %><br>
  <%= f.collection_select(:favorite_color_id, @colors, :id, :name, :include_blank => "Please select") %>
</div>

# index

<td><%= contact.favorite_color.name %></td>
```

Comment: both answers posted have led me to what I assume is the next error in my code. Getting the error undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass in _form. Researching it, it seems as though maybe something is missing from my contactcontroller in the def new and/or def update. I will keep poking and maybe post a new question, but since you have both already looked at my code, might I ask if anything in the controller jumps out at you?

Comment: I should ad that the error specifically (according to an older post on SO) is generated because collection_select calls map on the argument, under the hood